# how to produce a 'fatjar' for a simple console application with gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a simple app... but consider that even "hello world" would work as an example.  I am building with gradle kotlin dsl.

I have applied the application plugin, and set mainClassName, but the only jar I get (in /build/libs) does not contain the libraries so cannot be simply run with "java filename".  In fact, for some reason I still need to give it a main class as well.

But my real question, "what is what easiest way to produce the jar with libraries(fat jar) as an artifact?"

I would have thought the application plugin would have an option for that?

Comment: The `application` plugin does not build a JAR that you can run with `java filename`. Instead, its `distZip` and `distTar` tasks produce an archive that contains all of the classes and dependencies along with shell scripts for Windows and Unix that run the application. You can use the `shadow` plugin to pack the classes and dependencies together in into a single JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hotkey pointed out you can use the https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow plugin like so:

In your depedencies and the following:

```
classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:<version>'
```

Replace `<version>` with the current version.

And apply the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

Then you are able to use the `shadowJar` task.

Comment: to add ShadowJar, this is the Kotlin DSL syntax?

Comment: This is the gradle syntax.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options to do it with Gradle Kotlin DSL:

1. Build your own task. 
   An example is given in Gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example)

   ```
   tasks.register<Jar>("uberJar") {
       appendix = "uber"

       from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

       dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
       from({
           configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar")}.map { zipTree(it) }
       })
   }
   ```
2. Use [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)

   ```
   plugins {
       id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "4.0.4"
   }
   ```

   It will add **shadowJar** task, that can be invoked like this: `gradle build shadowJar` or `gradle build shadowJar -x test` to skip tests

   It's often needed to include logging, which can be done like that:

   ```
   import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar
   import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.Log4j2PluginsCacheFileTransformer

   tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
       // the name of the file will be comprised of the basename and version, e.g. $baseName-$version.jar
       baseName = "shadow"
       transform(Log4j2PluginsCacheFileTransformer::class.java)
   }
   ```